# Waiting for an asynchronous function in clean JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm currently working with XMLHttpRequest() and as a result I have an asynchronous function. I want to be able to run some code after the XMLHttpRequest is finished. My code so far:

```
var method = function() {
    this.func = function(param) {
        _xmlrequestfunc(param, function(r) {
            // return something
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to be able to do with this function is the following:

```
method.func('POST').Then(
    // Do something when method.func() is finished
)
```

I would like to do this in clean JavaScript... Is this possible and if so can anyone explain how it is done? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have it in clean JS, you can return this self-made promise from your `func()`:

```
var promise = {
    resolve: function (data) {
        this.callback(data);
    },
    Then: function (callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }
};

_xmlrequestfunc(param, function(r) {
    promise.resolve(42);
});

return promise;
```

This way you can use return value as you wanted:

```
method.func('POST').Then(function (theAnswer) {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a function as callback...

```
this.func = function(param, callback) {
    _xmlrequestfunc(param, function(r) {
        if(callback) callback();
        // return something
    }
}

.....
this.func({yourprams}, responseFunc);

function responseFunc() {
    //I am being called after the successful completion of XMLRequest.
}
```